# Steam-user помогите узнать Nickname

Tags: javascript, node.js, steam

Привет, у меня вопрос. Как можно через Steam-user узнать ник, который отправил сообщение? 
Вот мой код:

```
console.log("Получено сообщение: " + steamID.getSteam3RenderedID() + ": " + 
message);
```

При отправке сообщения, пишет мой SteamID, а нужно ник, если такое возможно.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашёл ответ, просто используйте этот код:

```
client.getPersonas([steamID], function (persona) {

       partnerName = persona[steamID].player_name;
       console.log(partnerName);
});
```